# Label next to reference in abbrvnat

Tags: bibliographies

I am using the abbrvnat style, but I want the label to appear next to each reference. For example, I want to have:

```
[Atzori et al., 2010] L. Atzori, A. Iera, and G. Morabito. The Internet 
of Things: A Survey. Computer Networks, 54(15):2787-2805, 2010.
```

Instead of :

```
L. Atzori, A. Iera, and G. Morabito. The Internet of Things: A Survey. 
Computer Networks, 54(15):2787-2805, 2010.
```

In the following code:

%File: Temp.tex\

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}\

\usepackage{setspace}\
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm] {geometry}\
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}\
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\
\usepackage[english]{babel}\
\usepackage[square]{natbib}\

\begin{document}\
\begin{abstract}\
The IoT~\citep{ref1}\
\end{abstract}\
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}\
\bibliography{biblioTemp}\
\end{document}\
```

%File: biblioTemp.bib\

```
@article{ref1,\
    author = {Luigi Atzori and Antonio Iera and Giacomo Morabito},\
    title = {{The Internet of Things: A Survey}},\
    journal = {Computer Networks},\
    volume = {54},\
    number = {15},\
    pages = {2787-2805},\
    year = {2010},\
    issn = {1389-1286}\
}\
```

%Output\

[image]

[image]

%Desired Output\

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please tell us a bit about the use case you have in mind. (All I can tell for now is that adding this extra stuff will create a huge amount of visual clutter without providing meaningul information to your readers...)

Comment: The addition of the label next to each reference facilitates the search. @Mico